# how to remove green color from input field in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-design, material-ui

Could you please tell me how to remove green color from input field in react? I know it is coming from the theme, I just want to remove from only for this form `input` and `select` field.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8k5xkvw869)

[image]

```jsx
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: green,
    secondary: green
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        color: "red",
        "&:hover:not($disabled):after": {},
        "&:hover:not($disabled):before": {}
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/ you have to override the styles.

Comment: can you please change my sandbox link

Comment: any update ? can you help me

Comment: I don't know how to do that offhand as I'm not familiar with the library. I gave you the link for direction. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: ok..thanks for help

Comment: which color you want to override ?

Comment: @no color same behiour

Comment: I need same color or same style before click `grey`

Comment: I need same color or same style before click `grey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked your code example and edited in the theme overrides to change the color of the form label https://codesandbox.io/s/j3763x65y3.

In the `test.js` file, i have edited in the following:

under styles:

```
  noUnderline: {
    color: "grey",
    "&:after": {
      borderColor: "grey",
      color: "grey"
    },
  }
```

and as properties for the respective TextField:

```
<TextField
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
            focused: false
          }}
          InputProps={{
            classes: {
              focused: classes.noUnderline,
              underline: classes.noUnderline
            }
          }}
</TextField>
```

I did not quickly find the right classes property to change the focused color of the InputLabel, so I just disabled the focus with `focused: false`, although this is not a very elegant solution and I would not use it in production.

Since the TextField component is a component composed from other components, check out the API docs for the component https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/ as well as for the components it is composed of.